# Make fields readonly if not current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, best-in-place

I am using the best in place gem and I want for the fields on a users profile that is not logged in (not current user) to be in readonly mode. ATM a user can be logged in, visit another users page and change their profile options (it won't save to the database). It should be setup so that if you're not the current user then all profile information will be readonly.

show.html.erb:

```
<p>Education: <%= best_in_place @user, :education, nil: 'What is your education level?', :type => :select, :collection => [["High school", "High school"], ["Some college", "Some college"], ["Undergraduate", "Undergraduate"], ["Bachelor's", "Bachelor's"], ["Master's", "Master's"], ["PhD", "PhD"], ["Business school", "Business school"], ["Law school", "Law school"], ["Medical school", "Medical school"]] %></p>
```

Users controller:

```
   def update
      @user = if current_user.has_role?(:admin)
            User.find(params[:id])
          else
            current_user
          end
         @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
         respond_with @user
        end

 def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what the best in place gem does, but for a regular form, you'd need to add the `readonly: true` option into the fields in the view. I assumed that your `edit` view also provides the `@user` instance variable to the view.

Something like:

```
<% if current_user.id == @user.id %>
  <p>Education: <%= best_in_place @user, :education, nil: 'What is your education level?', :type => :select, :collection => [["High school", "High school"], ["Some college", "Some college"], ["Undergraduate", "Undergraduate"], ["Bachelor's", "Bachelor's"], ["Master's", "Master's"], ["PhD", "PhD"], ["Business school", "Business school"], ["Law school", "Law school"], ["Medical school", "Medical school"]] %></p>
<% else %>
  <p>Education: <%= best_in_place @user, :education, nil: 'What is your education level?', :type => :select, :collection => [["High school", "High school"], ["Some college", "Some college"], ["Undergraduate", "Undergraduate"], ["Bachelor's", "Bachelor's"], ["Master's", "Master's"], ["PhD", "PhD"], ["Business school", "Business school"], ["Law school", "Law school"], ["Medical school", "Medical school"]], readonly: true %></p>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

It seems that normal Rails helper options aren't available, so try adding the HTML disabled attribute directly, like so:

```
<% if current_user.id == @user.id %>
  <p>Education: <%= best_in_place @user, :education, nil: 'What is your education level?', :type => :select, :collection => [["High school", "High school"], ["Some college", "Some college"], ["Undergraduate", "Undergraduate"], ["Bachelor's", "Bachelor's"], ["Master's", "Master's"], ["PhD", "PhD"], ["Business school", "Business school"], ["Law school", "Law school"], ["Medical school", "Medical school"]] %></p>
<% else %>
  <p>Education: <%= best_in_place @user, :education, nil: 'What is your education level?', :type => :select, :collection => [["High school", "High school"], ["Some college", "Some college"], ["Undergraduate", "Undergraduate"], ["Bachelor's", "Bachelor's"], ["Master's", "Master's"], ["PhD", "PhD"], ["Business school", "Business school"], ["Law school", "Law school"], ["Medical school", "Medical school"]], :html_attrs => {:disabled => true} %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that has no effect. I am still able to click on the text and select the other options.

Comment: See above edit, it seems that gem doesn't give you the normal form helpers. Can I ask why, instead of rendering the input as read-only, you don't want to just render out the information in the view instead?

Comment: I wanted users to be able to visit their profile page and edit directly without having to go to a official 'edit' page to change their profile information. Less navigation for the user making it a better experience overall. BTW the code works, thanks. I am going to make some adjustments but it gets the job done as is.